# Indicators Not Working But Hazard Lights Working

Tags: fuse, indicators, fuse-panel, pajero

Vehicle: Mitsubishi Pajero 1994

I have a 1994 Pajero and had a strange problem happen this morning, in the middle of driving the indicators strangely stopped working but when I pulled up the hazard lights where working.

Comment: This symptom could also be the indicator stalk contacts for indicators.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Traced this problem to a fuse under the dashboard, located in the middle horizontal row right most fuse. Turns out this fuse is the indicator fuse and when this fuse is blown the indicators won't work but the hazard lights still work.

This was the solution in my specific instance but there are two other possible faults which could be to blame for indicators not working...

1. Indicator Stalk - The switch contacts in the control stalk could be at fault (thanks @alex).
2. Hazard Light Switch - It may seem counter-intuitive that if the hazard lights work then the hazard switch is at fault, however the wiring from the indicator control stalk goers through the hazard control switch as the hazard switch effectively acts as the control stalk but applies power to both indicator light circuits at the same time. Due to the fact that the hazard light switch does not get frequently used the wires can come loose from the back of the switch or the switch can get a fault so if the fuse and the stalk seem in good nick then check the hazard switch.

Comment: On some vehicles (one example being the 1994–2001 Audi A4) even the relay for the turn signal and hazard lights is built into the hazard light switch.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Your tip was spot on. I can't believe I missed that fuse. I thought I checked all of them. I have a Citroen Synergie van but it was the same set up.