# Indicators and speedometer don't work, hazard lights do - is this a problem of the flasher relay?

Tags: relay, speedometer, astra, indicators, holden

I've recently been working on my wife's car, a Holden Astra 2000, replacing the blower motor resistor.

Somehow, since doing this work, the indicators and speedometer have stopped working, yet the hazards do still work.

One possible reason for this, was erroneously connecting the glovebox lights wires into the new resistor, instead of the correct resistor wires - so something like a blown fuse makes sense.

From the googling I've done re: 'indicators not working but hazards do' - people are suggesting either the timer relay is broken, or the indicator fuse is broken.

As far as I can see - the Holden Astra doesn't have fuses for the indicators themselves, see the fuse diagram from the owner manual:

[image]

Other answers have suggested that [perhaps the indicator stalk is as fault](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27052/indicators-not-working-but-hazard-lights-working), but this seems like too much of a coincidence that the fault only started happening when I started working on the car. Also - this wouldn't explain why the speedometer isn't working.

I removed the flasher relay and this stops the hazards from working as well - which suggests that flasher relay is at least partially working.

Does the flasher relay also provide functionality to speedometer?

In terms of cheaply fixing this problem - I'm considering replacing the flasher relay  and seeing if that solves it - the question is whether I'm missing something else that explains these faults.

Comment: Did you disconnect the battery before working on the Glove box lights, Its most likely a blown fuse

Comment: @hellomoto - Yes - but then reconnected the battery to check if it was working. In any case - going by the fuse diagram I've posted -which fuse woudl it be?

Comment: Is there only one fuse panel, you should have one in the car and another under the hood

Comment: If there isn’t another fusebox I would check fuse 22 first.

Comment: @hellomoto - ah I didnt realise there were two fuse boxes. There is a bonnet fuse box, but I don't know what they relate to.

Comment: @HandyHowie thanks for pointing that  out, I just realized that theres two hazard warning light fuses, that's weird. I'm sure one of those is probably blown

Comment: I know its a pain in the neck, but at this point, you should probably check each and every fuse in both boxes.  If you are lucky, you can use a flashlight and a small dental type inspection mirror to shine light thru top portion of the blade fuse, and check them withOUT removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blown fuse was number **29** on the shown diagram (the inside car fuses).

The diagram says: **Hazard warning flasher, courtesy light, auto trans** which isn't particularly helpful, but there you go, it apparently controls the indicators and speedo as well.

Comment: They wernt to clear on that were they, I guess they classify the courtesy lights as the indicator and the transmission is tied into the speedometer, I was working on a van a few years back that didnt have any cluster lights, turns out it was a memory fuse, who knew 